# Can a dockerfile interact with system settings?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've just recently started messing around with Docker and I was wondering if it is possible for a dockerfile to interact with system settings like turning off wi-fi or bluetooth? According to what I know so far, dockerfiles should do the same thing no matter where they run, so how can you generalize something like this across different OS's? Wouldn't you need if-statements in this case? For example the terminal command to turn off wi-fi on linux might be different on Windows so you would need to check which OS docker is running on and you should also be able to check if the machine running this dockerfile even has bluetooth.

Comment: This question isn't really about docker. Docker is a means to deploy an application. Think about how you would create any script to accomplish this , then wrap it up in a docker container.

Comment: @stacksonstacks why would I wrap it up in a container then?

Comment: Dockerfiles are for building container environments. Their commands are run at build time. Say you write a dockerfile to change the host's bluetooth setting, when a container eventually runs from this image, the host settings may have changed. Therefore you'd want to do this change within a container at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You specify your dockerfile commands based on what OS you will have inside the docker container. If let's say you have the centos base, you would use yum to install things. If you use debian based that would be apt-get.

Comment: Alright I understand that, what if the container wants to interact with the host computer's settings? So assume a windows computer is running a container that uses Ubuntu for example.

Comment: Docker containers not meant to be modified host computer settings. You can expose the container ports for host computer to use though.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that the best you could do is have the container send "signals" to the host machine indicating that it would need to perform an action.

For example, perhaps the container would place a file in a volume-mapped directory that the host machine would watch for. Then it would be up to the host machine to run its own logic to perform the action.

In other words, the container should stay oblivious to the details of how the host machine runs.